# What operations are safe on a shared git repository?

Tags: git

When cloning a git repository using the `--shared` option, which operations are safe on the origin repository? Specifically, if run `git fetch origin` in the original repository, can the cloned repository become corrupt?

For example, given repository `~/repos/foo.git` (it is a bare git repository), when I create a new repository using `git clone --shared ~/repos/foo.git`, and then, inside `~/repos/foo.git` I run `git fetch origin`, can the cloned repository become corrupt?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to come up with a canonical source that says whether `git-fetch` ever deletes orphaned objects (i.e., if it ever triggers `git gc --auto`). But if you want to make sure auto-garbage-collection never runs, you can stick this in the config of your bare, source repository:

```
git config --global gc.auto 0
```

This will prevent it from ever running GC automatically. Other than an auto-gc, `git-fetch` isn't going to delete objects (it might delete refs depending on your configuration, but the worst that's going to do is make objects orphaned, which is fine as long as *you never GC*). The manpage for `git-fetch` calls out explicitly that any operations in the source repo are fine as long as they don't delete existing objects.